# Accesing GPS location error on Android

Tags: android, gps, location

I tried to get GPS location but it shows following error

```
09-21 16:01:57.316: E/AndroidRuntime(8775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 16:01:57.316: E/AndroidRuntime(8775): java.lang.NullPointerException
"09-21 16:01:57.316: E/AndroidRuntime(8775):    at com.mgrs.converter.pro.Geocoord.getLocation(Geocoord.java:26)"
```

I tried to fix it but I dont know how to correct it.

please help

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView site1_lat, site1_lon, site2_lat, site2_lon, distance_kilo, distance_miles, azimuth1_content, azimuth2_content;
    TextView current_lat, current_lon, current_mgrs_result;
    Variables vari;

    //for geoCoord
    //Context mContext;
    LocationManager mLocMan;
    String mProvider;
    //Location location;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //for geoCoord
        //mLocMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //mProvider = mLocMan.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
        //LocationListener mListener = new Geocoord();

        //mLocMan.requestLocationUpdates(mProvider, 6000, 10, mListener);
        //

    //Button 0
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //1st site
        EditText mgrs_site1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String site1 = mgrs_site1.getText().toString().toUpperCase();

        Converter converter = new Converter();
        Geocoord geocoord = new Geocoord();
        geocoord.getLocation(context);

        converter.MGRStoUTM(site1);

        ///get Lat, Longitude
        site1_lat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.site1_lat);
        site1_lon = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.site1_lon);     
        site1_lat.setText(String.format("%6f", converter.getinitLat()));
        site1_lon.setText(String.format("%6f", converter.getinitLon()));

        //2nd site
        EditText mgrs_site2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String site2 = mgrs_site2.getText().toString().toUpperCase();   
        converter.MGRStoUTM(site2);

        ///get Lat, Longitude
        site2_lat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.site2_lat);
        site2_lon = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.site2_lon);     
        site2_lat.setText(String.format("%6f", converter.getinitLat()));
        site2_lon.setText(String.format("%6f", converter.getinitLon()));

        //current Lat, Longitude
        current_lat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_lat);
        current_lon = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_lon);

        current_lat.setText(String.format("%6f", converter.getLatitude()));
        current_lon.setText(String.format("%6f", converter.getLongitude()));

        //get current MGRS
        String str;
        converter.LLtoMGRS(converter.getLatitude(),converter.getLongitude(),10);
        str=converter.getMGRS();
        System.out.println("MGRS result");
        System.out.println(str);

        current_mgrs_result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_mgrs_result);
        current_mgrs_result.setText(str);


    }
    }); //ends button0

    //Button 1

    }//ends onCreate

}//ends Activity
```

**Geocoord.java**

```
public class Geocoord {
    Variables vari;
    Context mContext;
    LocationManager mLocMan;
    String mProvider;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;


    public void getLocation(Context context){
        mContext = context;
        mLocMan = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mProvider = mLocMan.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
        mLocMan.requestLocationUpdates(mProvider, 6000, 10, mListener);

    }

        LocationListener mListener =new LocationListener(){
          public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            setLatitude(latitude);
            setLongitude(longitude);
          }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("provider disabled");

        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("provider enabled");

        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("status changed");
        }


    };


    public void setLatitude(double gps_latitude)
    {vari.gps_latitude = gps_latitude;}
    public void setLongitude(double gps_longitude)
    {vari.gps_longitude = gps_longitude;}

    public double getLatitude()
    {return vari.gps_latitude;}
    public double getLongitude()
    {return vari.gps_longitude;}


}
```

Comment: can you post fulltrack trace.are you using device or emulator?

Comment: what is line 26 of Geocoord.java

Answer (score 0):

You pass a context via Geocoord.getLocation(context). But this context is never initialized, and is null.

Pass the this pointer of the Activity like this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    //1st site
    EditText mgrs_site1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String site1 = mgrs_site1.getText().toString().toUpperCase();

    Converter converter = new Converter();
    Geocoord geocoord = new Geocoord();
    geocoord.getLocation(MainActivity.this); // use the MainActivitys context
    ...
}
}
```

Now you can get rid of the Context field in your Activity and the NPE should be gone.